# setting a random position parameter in ros gazebo python

Tags: gazebo, ros-noetic

I am trying to get a vehicle to launch at a **random position** in **gazebo**. However, whenever it launches after changing the `threshold` in `randomize_params` script it does change the position but if I close the `sim` and relaunch, it goes back to the default positions from the **launch file**. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

I have a class in gazebo where is am initializing a position of a vehicle, I created another `node/script` that should set the `params` to random numbers between a threshold

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('randomize_params_node')
    max_threshold = 5.0  # Adjust this threshold according to your needs
    new_x = random.uniform(-max_threshold, max_threshold)
    new_y = random.uniform(-max_threshold, max_threshold)

    rospy.spin()
```

Also before setting the `params` I tried deleting any `params` that were there with My launch file contains:

- default params
- randomized parameters node
- control node where the `self.veh_x` and `self.veh_y` variables are initially set (see above).

Comment: please provide more details: `launch file`, and "*class in gazebo*", also note that you are **not publishing the randomized values** in the code above!

Answer (score 2):

One issue that I see here is, you are not actually setting the parameters that you are randomizing, you have to use the `rospy.set_param()` function to do this.

Here is an updated code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('randomize_params_node')
    max_threshold = 5.0  # Adjust this threshold according to your needs
    
    new_x = random.uniform(-max_threshold, max_threshold)
    new_y = random.uniform(-max_threshold, max_threshold)

    rospy.set_param("vehicle_x", new_x)
    rospy.set_param("vehicle_y", new_y)

    rospy.spin()
```

You have to launch this file before launching Gazebo to make sure that the positions are initialized before the simulation is launched